# Zf2 Redis Adapter, getItems using wildcards

Tags: zend-framework2, redis

I'm making my first steps in using Redis under ZF2.
I was wondering if there is a method to retrieve keys by pattern.

e.g.:
after setting multiple values with keys like: 'stackOverflow_'.time(), i would like to retrieve later all keys matching the 'stackOverflow_' pattern.

tried using getItems(array $keys) with wildcard in: \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\AbstractAdapter.php

```
$redisKeyPattern = 'stackOverflow_'; 
$redis = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Redis');
$values = $redis->getItems(array($redisKeyPattern.'*'));
```

with no succces.

any ideas?

---

UDPATE:
thanks guys. i ended up with duplicating the Redis adapter and adding my own functionality that utilizes the 'keys' function in the Redis extension:

```
 public function getItemsByKeyPattern($pattern) {

    $keys = $this->getRedisResource()->keys('*'.$pattern.'*'); 
    if(empty($keys)) return null;

    foreach($keys as &$key){        
        $key = explode(':', $key)[1];
    }

    $items = parent::getItems($keys);
    return $items;
}
```

and it works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

sadly to say there is no method present to return items with a wildcard, also redis don't support namespaces for stored items.

you need to define each item you want to receive, maybe you should look at a implementation like this

```
$receiveRedisKeys = [];
foreach($resultSet as $result)
{
    $receiveRedisKeys[] = 'predefined_prefix_' . $result->getId();
}

$redisCacheResultSet = $redis->getItems($receiveRedisKeys);
```

i know that someone on github made a new repository where he modified redis to allow `namespaces` but this requires that you build the redis binarys by yourself from source. this leeds to a redis version you can't update anymore over `apt-get`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, but there are some alternatives.

One idea is to keep a set with the keys you are interested in. That is the most common approach to this problem: each time you create one of the keys you will want to retrieve later, you add its name to a set. Then when you need to operate on one of those keys, you can grab it from the set. Read [this article](http://redis.io/topics/twitter-clone) to get a general idea about this approach.

Another idea is to use the `SCAN` command to walk the keyspace with the pattern you are using, and as a second step retrieve the values with `MGET` followed by the keys you collected. This approach is good for administrative processes, but not as something that should be included in an application because the performance will be worse than that of the first idea. More about [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan).

Finally, an option that is not recommended but I'm listing it just for completeness is to use the `KEYS` command to collect the keys you want, then proceed to get the values with `MGET`, as in the `SCAN` approach. This is not recommended as `KEYS` shouldn't be used in production environments. More about [KEYS](http://redis.io/commands/keys).